# Android add Library error

Tags: java, android

Hello i use a Cropper library i add a project with android wizards but in xml mark a error

```
import com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;
CropImageView crop_image_view;
```

work fine ok import
**my xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/crop_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:aspectRatioX="5"
        custom:showGuidelines="onTouch"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Rendering Problems NOTE This project contains Java compilation errors which can cause rendering failures for custom views Fix compilation problems first

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: name expected (position:START_TAG <null>@4:59 in java.io.StringReader@eb8d000)
```

**my gradlie:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':cropper')
}
```

where ir my error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with adding dependency like below:

```
compile 'com.edmodo:cropper:1.0.1'
```